# How to Implement multi category using tabs in an RSS feed app?

Tags: java, android, rss, rss-reader

I Want to implement multi category in rss feed app, i created a method Downloader which works properly in mainactivity.

But Downloader Method not works in tab fragments.

Here is screenshot of my project and Downloader method.

click here for project screenshot

[image]

[image]

When i implement downloader method in fragment, it shows an error.

context c is not resolve here

[here is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSxtv.jpg)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
     recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    new Downloader(c,urlAddress,recyclerview).execute();

    return view;
}
```

comment if you need any other information.

Comment: means you want to show downloader method in fragment ?

Comment: yes i want to show downloader method in fragment

Comment: can you provide code how you code in fragment ?

Comment: yes i give you screenshot

Comment: try to put code here

Answer (score 0):

You defined in the signature of your class that the first parameter should be context. You try to pass an undefined variable called c in your code thats why c gets highlighted as error. To fix your code either define c or directly pass in an context into the constructor.

You can get the context by calling `getContext()`and it should work:

`new Downloader(getContext(), urlAddress, recyclerview).execute();`